# OxyPlot sum series

Tags: c#, winforms, oxyplot

I have an Oxyplot chart with two LineSeries and I would like to add a new LineSeries which is sum of the two original LineSeries.

How can I create the Sum LineSeries?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var myModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Example 1" };
        myModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(function1, 0, 100, 0.1, "a*1"));
        myModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(function2, 0, 100, 0.1, "b*2"));

        this.plotView1.Model = myModel;
    }

    public double function1(double a)
    {
        double result = 0;
        result = a * 1;
        return result;
    }

    public double function2(double b)
    {
        double result = 0;
        result = b * 2;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just need to create another function:

```
public double function3(double b)
{
   return function1(b) + function2(b);
}
```

and then

```
myModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(function3, 0, 100, 0.1, "a+b*2"));
```